# How to use Proguard in Kotlin Multiplatform (KMM) shared module

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, minify, kotlin-multiplatform

This is my `:shared->build.gradle.kts` file

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("maven-publish")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.1"

kotlin {
    android {
        publishLibraryVariants("release", "debug")
    }
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                with(Deps.Koin) {
                    api(core)
                    api(test)
                }
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 32
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

1. When I run `shared -> [publishAndroidReleasePublicationToMavenLocal]` Gradle task. The generated `.aar` file does not show any contents in it. It lacks all `.class` files in `classes.jar`. Also local dependency of this .aar does not compile.
2. When I run `shared -> [publishAndroidDebugPublicationToMavenLocal]` Gradle task. It works as expected. Having all .class in it without any obfuscation. It works as local dependency.

I am following steps from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-library.html#publish-your-library-to-the-external-maven-central-repository

I must obfuscate my shared code somehow. How can I do it properly?

Any working KMM sample that uses Proguard or any other tool for obfuscation?

I have tried

```
publications.register<MavenPublication>("release") {

            groupId = "com.example"
            artifactId = "demo"
            version = "0.1"

            from(components.getByName("release"))

            pom {
                .......
            }
}
```

Nothing worked. Same results as above.
Please help.